# Connection to Windows Server 2012 R2 via RDC only possible with script?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to connect with my Windows Server 2012 r2 via Remote Desktop Connection. This is not possible by calling the Remote Desktop Connection Programm with my mouse(by clicking). If i right-click on the Program and run it as Administrator it is also not possible to connect to the Server.

Error Message:
Die Verbindung mit der Remotesitzung wurde getrennt, da kein Lizenzserver für Remotedesktop vorhanden sind.
Wenden Sie sich an den Serveradministrator.
(in german)

The remote session was disconnected because there are no Remote Desktop License Servers available to provide a license.
(in english)

Now i wrote a Little script:

```
mstsc.exe /admin
```

By Running this script i can connect with my Server. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Can anybody help me with my issue.